# Samsung Note 8.0 is mdpi large or mdpi extralarge device?

Tags: android

I submitted my app to samsung app store but it is rejected as it fails on Tablet Galaxy(WXGA) devices.
I don't know the bug.I tested the app through remote test lab devices but I am unable to open even a single device.It just shows a black screen.

Can you please tell me some other way to test the application on Samsung Note 8.0 or samsung galaxy tab 10.1..?

If it's not possible then please tell me that Whether **Samsung note 8.0** device is ldpi/mdpi/hdpi.xhdpi device with screen size as small/normal/large/extra large,So that I can figure out the bug..?

Answer (score 1):

Note 8.0 is hdpi-large last time we checked.

Comment: Is the newest version still hdpi? Does somebody know where I can check that?

Comment: This was the Note 8 in question: https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_8_0-5252.php